# AEM6: Adding new language

Tags: aem

I want to add a new language to AEM6. I have added /apps/wcm/core/resources/languages from /libs/wcm/core/resources/languages and changed the path langmgr.list.path at 
http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr/com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.LanguageManagerImpl. I have also added the language ilo_ph under /apps/wcm/core/resources/languages and added the country Properties with value Philippines. When I create the page ilo_ph parallel to other pages such as en_US etc, I am not able to see the country flag under Tools --> Language Copy. What do I need to do to be able to see the language and respective flag under Tools --> Language Copy.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, AEM language copy doesn't support language codes with more than 2 letters. Hence it might have been ignored in the Language copy dialog.

Quoting the docs

> The supported language code is lower-case, two-letter code as defined by ISO-639-1 and the supported country code is lower-case or upper-case, two-letter code as defined by ISO 3166

Refer [administering languages page](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/administer/sites/languages.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The language code is ilo as per ISO 639-3. Does that means I can't add it to AEM ?

Comment: Well as mentioned above, ISO-639-1 are the one's currently supported. However i guess we might be able to work around this by some level of customization, which i haven't tried yet. Will update in case it is successful.

Comment: Ok thanks. Let me know if you have any ideas and I can give it a try too.